# php date & strtotime function resulting in 1970-00-00 00:00 value

Tags: php

As ive echoed out the datetime value from my db, i am now trying to display this value to edit it in the datetime-local field within my form.
The datetime vaue from db is set to:
22/3/2017 10:00:00

however, after attempting to use the following code, im left with this:
1970-01-01T01:00:00

```
 $dat = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($_GET["dat"]));
```

How & why is this function not working correctly to display '22/3/2017 10:00' in the form field?

Comment: Your date format is incorrect. There is no 22nd month. See the above duplicate for how to handle these date formats.

Comment: has `$dat=date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime('22/3/2017 10:00:00'));` same result?

Comment: The second paramater should be an integer, more specifically a unix timestamp. If none is provided, the current timestamp will be used. As it currently stands `strtotime` will result in an error. Long story short, the input of `strtotime` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks all! vp_arth answer solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date =  DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '22/3/2017 10:00:00');
$dat = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
echo $dat;
```

---

Your code is not working because `strtotime` makes assumption **based on delimiters** about actual format:

- `m/d/Y`- American format
- `d.m.Y` or `d-m-Y` - European

Comment: worked perfectly, and thanks for the information on the strtotime!

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `strtotime()` can translate only specific date format.

Check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). For a list of supported date format, look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

Your date format looks not included in the supported ones to me.

Examples:

```
strtotime("03/22/2017 10:00:00"); // Works: returns 1490173200
strtotime("22/3/2017 10:00"); // Doesn't work: returns false
```

You have to either change the date format in your DB or format it to one of the supported formats to make it work.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer as it does not adequately explain why this is incorrect nor show to to correct it

Comment: Updated. Thanks @JohnConde